# How do I refresh my UITableviewCell after downloading an image from the background

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uiimageview, xcode-storyboard

I have this code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9700869

Now my questions would be how to refresh the table after the image has been downloaded? Right now the images are not displaying initially, and I have to click on the row before the image appears:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QgS0.jpg

and

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUCUF.jpg

Second, I have limit the size of my cell row height to 70:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3tYP.jpg

somehow at runtime the row height increases. Please see 2nd image above showing the image

Thanks in advance.

Richard

Comment: I was able to fix my 1st issue: [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9701757)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so to solve my 2nd issue, I set my table view cell row height to default and style to subtile.

Thanks